# send a changed record of a SQL Server 2012 online database to an application

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, change-tracking, change-data-capture

I am programming an online game (such as chess) which two players can play together online.
each one of the players should have installed the game application (developed by C#) on their computers.
when a player do some action, a record of a database (SQL Server 2012) -which has been placed on the internet, will be changed.
My need: **when a record of this online database changes, whole the record send to both players' game application immediately.**
Thanks.

Comment: This should really be handled by web service caching.  Save to the database only if you need to persist the data (ie save the game and come back to it later).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write some backservice. Look at [service broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb522893.aspx). I think, it is perfect solution for you application. The workflow is:

1. Player sends request to the first back service
2. Back service inserts into **service broker queue**
3. Second service reads the queue and inserts data to database and sends notivication to second player.

Because of **service broker queue** is transaction-based structure you can create a lot of instances of 'Second Service' to increase performance of your application.